# Log of the frequency in histogram

Tags: python, histogram

I plot the histogram of an array using `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`. If `Log = True`, the x axis will be set to log scale. I want the y axis to plot the log(frequency). How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

If by 'frequency' you mean the rate, i.e. the number of times a value occurs per second, then you can add the `weights` keyword argument to you `pyplot.hist()` call, as documented [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

You will need to give `weights` as an array with the same size as your data, so you can use

```py
weights = numpy.ones_like(x.shape) / duration
```

where `duration` is the total amount of time over which the data are valid.

Comment: By frequency I mean the (how many times a value appears)/(total number of values). I will give it a try now. Thanks.